# Pig macro does not take 'sh' in body

Tags: shell, macros, apache-pig

In Pig, this simple macro doesn't work:

```
define simple ()
returns void {
sh echo 'Hello World'
};

simple();
```

It gives this error:

```
2015-04-06 09:56:00,733 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 1200: <line 10> Failed to parse macro 'simple'. Reason: <line 2, column 0>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'sh'
macro content: 
sh echo 'Hello World'
```

Why is that?  If I just put the "sh echo 'Hello World'" on a line by itself, it's fine.  If I make more complex macros with data sets and return values and such, it works fine.  But trying to do sh fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apache Pig documentation:

> [Macros cannot contain Grunt shell commands.](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/cont.html#define-macros)